# how to pinvoke SLGetWindowsInformation from c#

Tags: c#, c++, types, pinvoke, type-conversion

i know how to pinvoke but the data structure given in this function is giving me more troubles than i could figure out on my own

function name is SLGetWindowsInformation exists at slc.dll

```
    HRESULT WINAPI SLGetWindowsInformation(
  _In_      PCWSTR     pwszValueName,
  _Out_opt_ SLDATATYPE *peDataType,
  _Out_     UINT       *pcbValue,
  _Out_     PBYTE      *ppbValue
);
```

for full reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965834(v=vs.85).aspx)

thanks in advance and have wonderful day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
enum SLDATATYPE 
{
    SL_DATA_NONE      = REG_NONE,
    SL_DATA_SZ        = REG_SZ,
    SL_DATA_DWORD     = REG_DWORD,
    SL_DATA_BINARY    = REG_BINARY,
    SL_DATA_MULTI_SZ  = REG_MULTI_SZ,
    SL_DATA_SUM       = 100
};
// you can look up the values of the REG_XXX constants from the windows header files    

[DllImport("Slc.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern uint SLGetWindowsInformation(
    string ValueName,
    out SLDATATYPE DataType,
    out uint cbValue,
    out IntPtr Value
);
```

Call the function like this:

```
SLDATATYPE DataType;
uint cbValue;
IntPtr ValuePtr;
uint res = SLGetWindowsInformation(ValueName, out DataType, out cbValue, out ValuePtr);
// check that res indicates success before proceeding
byte[] Value = new byte[cbValue];
Marshal.Copy(ValuePtr, Value, 0, Value.Length);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ValuePtr);
```

Note that it may seem a little confusing, but `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` actually calls `LocalFree`, so is the correct way to deallocate this buffer.

Comment: accepting the answer in 3 mins, good job, thanks for your help